# Update an ember.js view when content is dropped

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to implement drag and drop with Ember.js.  I have everything working except getting the view to update at the end.  Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rsaNy/

If you drag something from the source list and drop it in the dest div, I want it to be added to the display.  The two alerts that I have set up confirm that the data structures are actually being updated, but the update is not being reflected in the view.  How do I solve this?  Here's the code.

```
DragNDrop = Ember.Namespace.create();

DragNDrop.cancel = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

App = Ember.Application.create();

testItems =
  [ { name: "Alpha" } ,
    { name: "Bravo" } ,
    { name: "Charlie" } ];

App.SourceItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'sourceItem',
  tagName: 'li',
  attributeBindings: 'draggable',
  draggable: 'true',
  dragStart: function(event) {
      var dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
      var msg = this.get('content');
      dataTransfer.setData('text', JSON.stringify(msg));
  }
});

App.SourceView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'source',
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['well']
});

App.DestView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'dest',
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['well'],
  dragEnter: DragNDrop.cancel,
  dragLeave: DragNDrop.cancel,
  dragOver: DragNDrop.cancel,
  drop: function(event) {
      var c = this.get('content');
      var fieldStr = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
      alert(fieldStr);
      c.push(JSON.parse(fieldStr));

      var str = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        str += c[i].name+' ';
      }
      alert(str);

      return true;
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: { source: testItems,
             dest: [{name: "Delta"}] }
});
```

Comment: Is that the right Fiddle? It just has the default ember example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Ember Array `pushObject()` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject) instead of `push()`. This allows Ember to keep track of the data changes for it's binding system, which is how the view knows to update itself. It is the same idea of having to use `get()` and `set()` all the time.

```
drop: function(event) {
      var c = this.get('content');
      var fieldStr = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
      alert(fieldStr);
      c.pushObject(JSON.parse(fieldStr));
      //...
```

[Here is the working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsaNy/1/)